# Python code crashes when running, but not when debugging (Ctypes)

Tags: python, ctypes

I am running into a REALLY weird case with a little class involving ctypes that I am writing.  The objective of this class is to load a matrix that is in proprietary format into a python structure that I had to create (these matrices can have several cores/layers and each core/layer can have several indices that refer to only a few elements of the matrix, thus forming submatrices).

The code that test the class is this:

```
import numpy as np
from READS_MTX import mtx
import time

mymatrix=mtx()


mymatrix.load('D:\\MyMatrix.mtx', True)
```

and the class I created is this:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from  ctypes import *
import ctypes
import time


def main():
    pass


#A mydll mtx can have several cores
#we need a class to define each core
#and a class to hold the whole file together

class mtx_core:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name=None     #Matrix core name
        self.rows=-1       #Number of rows in the matrix
        self.columns=-1    #Number of columns in the matrix
        self.type=-1       #Data type of the matrix
        self.indexcount=-1 #Tuple with the number of indices for each dimension
        self.RIndex={}     #Dictionary with all indices for the rows
        self.CIndex={}     #Dictionary with all indices for the columns
        self.basedata=None
        self.matrix=None


    def add_core(self, mydll,mat,core):
        nameC=ctypes.create_string_buffer(50)
        mydll.MATRIX_GetLabel(mat,0,nameC)
        nameC=repr(nameC.value)
        nameC=nameC[1:len(nameC)-1]

        #Add the information to the objects' methods
        self.name=repr(nameC)
        self.rows= mydll.MATRIX_GetBaseNRows(mat)
        self.columns=mydll.MATRIX_GetBaseNCols(mat)
        self.type=mydll.MATRIX_GetDataType(mat)
        self.indexcount=(mydll.MATRIX_GetNIndices(mat,0 ),mydll.MATRIX_GetNIndices(mat,0 ))

        #Define the data type Numpy will have according to the data type of the matrix in question
        dt=np.float64
        v=(self.columns*c_float)()

        if self.type==1:
            dt=np.int32
            v=(self.columns*c_long)()
        if self.type==2:
            dt=np.int64
            v=(self.columns*c_longlong)()

        #Instantiate the matrix
        time.sleep(5)
        self.basedata=np.zeros((self.rows,self.columns),dtype=dt)

        #Read matrix and puts in the numpy array
        for i in range(self.rows):
            mydll.MATRIX_GetBaseVector(mat,i,0,self.type,v)
            self.basedata[i,:]=v[:]


        #Reads all the indices for rows and put them in the dictionary
        for i in range(self.indexcount[0]):
            mydll.MATRIX_SetIndex(mat, 0, i)
            v=(mydll.MATRIX_GetNRows(mat)*c_long)()
            mydll.MATRIX_GetIDs(mat,0, v)
            t=np.zeros(mydll.MATRIX_GetNRows(mat),np.int64)
            t[:]=v[:]
            self.RIndex[i]=t.copy()

        #Do the same for columns
        for i in range(self.indexcount[1]):
            mydll.MATRIX_SetIndex(mat, 1, i)
            v=(mydll.MATRIX_GetNCols(mat)*c_long)()
            mydll.MATRIX_GetIDs(mat,1, v)
            t=np.zeros(mydll.MATRIX_GetNCols(mat),np.int64)
            t[:]=v[:]
            self.CIndex[i]=t.copy()



class mtx:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data=None
        self.cores=-1
        self.matrix={}
        mydll=None

    def load(self, filename, verbose=False):
        #We load the DLL and initiate it
        mydll=cdll.LoadLibrary('C:\\Program Files\\Mysoftware\\matrixDLL.dll')
        mydll.InitMatDLL()

        mat=mydll.MATRIX_LoadFromFile(filename, True)

        if mat<>0:
            self.cores=mydll.MATRIX_GetNCores(mat)
            if verbose==True: print "Matrix has ", self.cores, " cores"
            for i in range(self.cores):
                mydll.MATRIX_SetCore(mat,i)
                nameC=ctypes.create_string_buffer(50)
                mydll.MATRIX_GetLabel(mat,i,nameC)
                nameC=repr(nameC.value)
                nameC=nameC[1:len(nameC)-1]
                #If verbose, we list the matrices being loaded
                if verbose==True: print "   Loading core: ", nameC

                self.datafile=filename
                self.matrix[nameC]=mtx_core()
                self.matrix[nameC].add_core(mydll,mat,i)
        else:
            raise NameError('Not possible to open file. TranCad returned '+ str(tc_value))


        mydll.MATRIX_CloseFile(filename)
        mydll.MATRIX_Done(mat)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run the test code in ANY form (double clicking, python's IDLE or Pyscripter) it crashes with the familiar error "WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000246", but when I debug the code using Pyscripter stoping in any inner loop, it runs perfectly.

I'd really appreciate any insights.

EDIT

THe Dumpbin output for the DLL:

File Type: DLL

Section contains the following exports for CaliperMTX.dll

```
00000000 characteristics
52FB9F15 time date stamp Wed Feb 12 08:19:33 2014
    0.00 version
       1 ordinal base
      81 number of functions
      81 number of names

ordinal hint RVA      name

      1    0 0001E520 InitMatDLL
      2    1 0001B140 MATRIX_AddIndex
      3    2 0001AEE0 MATRIX_Clear
      4    3 0001AE30 MATRIX_CloseFile
      5    4 00007600 MATRIX_Copy
      6    5 000192A0 MATRIX_CreateCache
      7    6 00019160 MATRIX_CreateCacheEx
      8    7 0001EB10 MATRIX_CreateSimple
      9    8 0001ED20 MATRIX_CreateSimpleLike
     10    9 00016D40 MATRIX_DestroyCache
     11    A 00016DA0 MATRIX_DisableCache
     12    B 0001A880 MATRIX_Done
     13    C 0001B790 MATRIX_DropIndex
     14    D 00016D70 MATRIX_EnableCache
     15    E 00015B10 MATRIX_GetBaseNCols
     16    F 00015B00 MATRIX_GetBaseNRows
     17   10 00015FF0 MATRIX_GetBaseVector
     18   11 00015CE0 MATRIX_GetCore
     19   12 000164C0 MATRIX_GetCurrentIndexPos
     20   13 00015B20 MATRIX_GetDataType
     21   14 00015EE0 MATRIX_GetElement
     22   15 00015A30 MATRIX_GetFileName
     23   16 00007040 MATRIX_GetIDs
     24   17 00015B80 MATRIX_GetInfo
     25   18 00015A50 MATRIX_GetLabel
     26   19 00015AE0 MATRIX_GetNCols
     27   1A 00015AB0 MATRIX_GetNCores
     28   1B 00016EC0 MATRIX_GetNIndices
     29   1C 00015AC0 MATRIX_GetNRows
     30   1D 00018AF0 MATRIX_GetVector
     31   1E 00015B40 MATRIX_IsColMajor
     32   1F 00015B60 MATRIX_IsFileBased
     33   20 000171A0 MATRIX_IsReadOnly
     34   21 00015B30 MATRIX_IsSparse
     35   22 0001AE10 MATRIX_LoadFromFile
     36   23 0001BAE0 MATRIX_New
     37   24 00017150 MATRIX_OpenFile
     38   25 000192D0 MATRIX_RefreshCache
     39   26 00016340 MATRIX_SetBaseVector
     40   27 00015C20 MATRIX_SetCore
     41   28 00016200 MATRIX_SetElement
     42   29 00016700 MATRIX_SetIndex
     43   2A 0001AFA0 MATRIX_SetLabel
     44   2B 00018E50 MATRIX_SetVector
     45   2C 00005DA0 MAT_ACCESS_Create
     46   2D 00005E40 MAT_ACCESS_CreateFromCurrency
     47   2E 00004B10 MAT_ACCESS_Done
     48   2F 00005630 MAT_ACCESS_FillRow
     49   30 000056D0 MAT_ACCESS_FillRowDouble
     50   31 00005A90 MAT_ACCESS_GetCurrency
     51   32 00004C30 MAT_ACCESS_GetDataType
     52   33 000058E0 MAT_ACCESS_GetDoubleValue
     53   34 00004C40 MAT_ACCESS_GetIDs
     54   35 00005AA0 MAT_ACCESS_GetMatrix
     55   36 00004C20 MAT_ACCESS_GetNCols
     56   37 00004C10 MAT_ACCESS_GetNRows
     57   38 000055A0 MAT_ACCESS_GetRowBuffer
     58   39 00005570 MAT_ACCESS_GetRowID
     59   3A 00005610 MAT_ACCESS_GetToReadFlag
     60   3B 00005870 MAT_ACCESS_GetValue
     61   3C 00005AB0 MAT_ACCESS_IsValidCurrency
     62   3D 000055E0 MAT_ACCESS_SetDirty
     63   3E 000059F0 MAT_ACCESS_SetDoubleValue
     64   3F 00005620 MAT_ACCESS_SetToReadFlag
     65   40 00005960 MAT_ACCESS_SetValue
     66   41 00005460 MAT_ACCESS_UseIDs
     67   42 00005010 MAT_ACCESS_UseIDsEx
     68   43 00005490 MAT_ACCESS_UseOwnIDs
     69   44 00004D10 MAT_ACCESS_ValidateIDs
     70   45 0001E500 MAT_pafree
     71   46 0001E4E0 MAT_palloc
     72   47 0001E4F0 MAT_pfree
     73   48 0001E510 MAT_prealloc
     74   49 00006290 MA_MGR_AddMA
     75   4A 00006350 MA_MGR_AddMAs
     76   4B 00005F90 MA_MGR_Create
     77   4C 00006050 MA_MGR_Done
     78   4D 000060D0 MA_MGR_RegisterThreads
     79   4E 00006170 MA_MGR_SetRow
     80   4F 00006120 MA_MGR_UnregisterThread
     81   50 0001E490 UnloadMatDLL
```

Summary

```
    6000 .data
    5000 .pdata
    C000 .rdata
    1000 .reloc
    1000 .rsrc
   54000 .text
```

Comment: Looks like there's something wrong with your ctypes call. But we cannot know that because you've not given details of the other side of the interop boundary.

Comment: What are you calling the other side of the interop boundary, David?  Is it the DLL? I posted the dumpbin output on the original question

Comment: Dumpin is no good. We need to know parameters, types, calling convention and semantics. Do you have any docs for the dll.

Comment: I would add a few logs to find where the exception occurs, would be easier if you narrow it down to a particular method call.

Comment: The default result type is a C `int`, i.e. in Python 2 ctypes uses `PyInt_FromLong(*(int *)result)`. Similarly for a parameter ctypes uses `pa->value.i = PyInt_AS_LONG(obj)`, where `i` is the `int` field of `union result`. So in a 64-bit process the pointer `mat` gets truncated to 32-bit if you haven't set `restype` and `argtypes` to use a pointer type such `c_void_p` or (preferably) an opaque pointer for this specific matrix type (i.e. a pointer to an empty `Structure` subclass).

Comment: I was able to narrow down the error to the mydll.MATRIX_SetIndex(mat, 0, i) call.  The software vendor has been pretty irresponsive to this issue, and the fact is that they do not really support python use. @eryksun - Point taken on the deprecation, but did not get the issue with truncation. I looked at the ctypes and dll documentations and matched the types to the best I could, thus using longlong in some places and long in others

Comment: The library is trying to write to the illegal address `0x246`; that means you have a bad pointer somewhere. For `mat = mydll.MATRIX_LoadFromFile`, if `mat` is a pointer then you need to set `MATRIX_LoadFromFile.restype` to a pointer type, else a 64-bit pointer is truncated to 32-bit, i.e. the upper 32 bits are set to 0.

Comment: @Eriksun,  Would it explain why the code runs well when I run it line by line with PyScripter and crashes otherwise (even when just running with Pyscripter)?